onEdit(e) not running when a non-google-user changes the cell value in Sheets
This is the function that runs fine when a signed-in user changes the cell value, but not when someone not signed-in:
It does simple things with the sheet itself and in unprotected ranges.
I have seen online that it should fire even if the file is open in a tab which is in incongnito mode, but it doesn't even show in the logs that the function has run.
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  const sheetsToWatch = ['Content Workbook'];

  if (sheetsToWatch.includes(sheet.getName())) {
    const headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns()).getValues()[0];
    const colToWatch = 'Client Feedback';
    const colToWatchIndex = headers.indexOf(colToWatch) + 1;
    const row = e.range.getRow();

    const colToSet = 'Feedback Processed';
    const colToSetIndex = headers.indexOf(colToSet) + 1;

    if (e.range.getColumn() === colToWatchIndex && row > 1) {
      const row = e.range.getRow();
      const timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
      sheet.getRange(row, colToSetIndex).setValue("No");
      sheet.getRange(row, colToSetIndex + 1).setValue(timestamp);
    }
  }
}


In your situation, how about modifying as follows?
Modified script
The function name is renamed from onEdit to installedOnEdit. And, please install the OnEdit trigger to installedOnEdit. Ref And test it again.
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  const sheetsToWatch = ['Content Workbook'];

  if (sheetsToWatch.includes(sheet.getName())) {
    const headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns()).getValues()[0];
    const colToWatch = 'Client Feedback';
    const colToWatchIndex = headers.indexOf(colToWatch) + 1;
    const row = e.range.getRow();

    const colToSet = 'Feedback Processed';
    const colToSetIndex = headers.indexOf(colToSet) + 1;

    if (e.range.getColumn() === colToWatchIndex && row > 1) {
      const row = e.range.getRow();
      const timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
      sheet.getRange(row, colToSetIndex).setValue("No");
      sheet.getRange(row, colToSetIndex + 1).setValue(timestamp);
    }
  }
}

Note:
As an important point, in your situation of when someone not signed-in, if you don't use user in the event object, no error occurs. If you use user in the event object, an error like You do not have permission to call Session.getActiveUser. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email occurs. Please be careful about this.

Hello! Thanks! I need this function to run on multiple files and the user should not have to grant any authorization for this to work. If I use the installablle trigger, this will require the user to grant authorization before it runs, right?

@onit Thank you for replying. About If I use the installable trigger, this will require the user to grant authorization before it runs, right?, when the installable trigger is used, the script is run by the owner. So, only the owner is required to authorize the scopes. Other users are not required to authorize the scopes.
